# MySQL Query to re-arrange columns and rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table view:

```
company_name    Status  Status_Created_Date
-------------------------------------------
Company A       StatusA   15/11/2014
Company A       StatusB   22/11/2014
Company B       StatusA   12/11/2014
Company B       StatusB   02/11/2014
```

and I would like to have a result like this:

```
company_name     StatusA         StatusB  
-------------------------------------------
Company A       15/11/2014
Company A                       22/11/2014
Company B       12/11/2014
Company B                       02/11/2014
```

Please give me your advice on how to build a query to get it done properly.

Comment: Any attempts on your own? A `case` statement might come in handy.

Comment: Can we see proper DDLs? And are you sure you want results on separate rows? If so, what determines the order?

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
select company_name,case when status='statusA' then Status_Created_Date 
else '' end "Status A",case when status='statusB' then Status_Created_Date 
else '' end "Status B" from table1
```